# Warning: Function return user-defined type which is incompatible with C

Tags: c++, xcode, llvm

Header:

```
using namespace std;
extern "C" {
  string testFunc();
}
```

.cpp:

```
string testFunc()
{
  return string("test");
}
```

I got this warning when building:

```
'testFunc' has C-linkage specified, but returns user-defined type 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') which is incompatible with C
```

I've test my function and "test" was returned properly.

Will this warning cause any issue?

I'm using Apple LLVM 4.2, C99, ALL default settings in XCode 4.6.

Comment: there's no such thing as `std::string` in `C`.

Comment: To be honest, this seems as clear as compiler errors get.

Comment: "I've test my function" -- not from C code.

Comment: LOL... that's the reason why it's not crashed... @JimBalter

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Presumably you are wrapping the declaration of `testFunc` in `extern "C"` because you want to be able to call it from a C program. However, when a C program calls this function, they're going to get a `std::string` back, which is completely incompatible with C. The program will just have no way to manage it.

Either `testFunc` shouldn't be inside `extern "C"` or it should be returning the string in a C-style way (perhaps as a `const char*`).

For a class type to be compatible with C, it should be a *standard-layout class* (in C++11 terminology).

> A standard-layout class is a class that:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> - has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
> - has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members,
> - has no non-standard-layout base classes,
> - either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
> - has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.

It should also not have its name mangled, which occurs when the type is in a namespace or when it is a template type.

Comment: @ReckHou Because the standard doesn't say this is ill-formed. The compiler is just warning you that returning a `std::string` is not compatible with C linkage. You'll certainly have problems if you try to call this function from C.

Comment: It's not that it doesn't have its name mangled; it's that the name gets mangled in the C style instead of the C++ style, typically by prepending an underscore, but some compilers (used to?) append an underscore. There's no standard mangling here, so `extern "C"` says to do whatever the compiler implementor thinks will work.